# Can I use my web server to host my rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

I have now build my first Ruby on Rails site and I want to publish/deploy/show it to the world on internet. I have access to space on a web server trough a university that I am associated with. But after some searching I realized that publishing a Rails site is slightly more complicated than publishing a regular html production.

Is there any way to use the space I have? How can I know if the server I have access to is up for the task? Is there any guides on how to do this via SSH or git or whatever? I have search a lot but not found anything useful. It doesn't have to be easy, I just have to work. And it's good if I can learn and understand what I am doing.

I have tried quite extensively to make it work with Heroku (everybody claims it to be so easy) but failed since it will not accept my push. Probably because I use Rails 4.2.2 (I don't want to change this, too many things stopped working when I tried to update) and Paperclip which seems to be known issues.

Please, I'm getting desperate, any help pointing in the right direction is very appreciated.

Comment: digital ocean has some decent guides https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tags/ruby-on-rails?q=deploy&type=tutorials

Comment: It's very unlikely you'll be able to host it on your university server, but Rails 4.2.x works fine on Heroku. So does Paperclip, but you'll need to switch the storage back end to S3 or some other external service instead of local file storage.

Comment: Here is a great free online ruby on rails tutorial that demonstrates how to publish to heroku (amongst many other things): [https://www.railstutorial.org/book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book)

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance and suggestions. I got it running now with S3 and Heroku – Yay! I think the major issues was to implement S3 correctly and switch from SQLite3 to PostgreSQL.